# Setting flashvars parameter of swf object dynamically

Tags: javascript, flash, flashvars

I have a rquirement where i want to play the song based on the checkbox checked.I mean i want to set the flashvars parameter of swf object on click of checkbox to play respective song.I am using the tag for this is

```
<embed type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
    flashvars="audioUrl=http://www.labnol.org/assets/mp3/unofficial-yahoo-song.mp3"
    src="http://www.google.com/reader/ui/3523697345-audio-player.swf" 
    width="400" 
    height="27" 
    quality="best"/>
```

in my website.Here i want to change the flasvars dynamically on checkbox(function as radion button) checked

Answer (score 1):

A `flashvar` is passed only once when the swf is loaded, so changing the html after that (via jQuery for instance) won't work.

Instead, use `ExternalInterface` to call a function within your swf via javascript which in turn starts or stops the player/change tracks.